# Why will only one of five embedded youtube videos play?

Tags: html, youtube, embed

I've embedded five youtube videos to a web page using the  code direct from youtube. If I only embed one video, it plays fine but if I add more than one then only the last one will play. All the other videos seem to have their controls disabled somehow.

All these videos are inside a DIV element in a simple html page and are separated by double 
 tags to stack them on top of each other.

My code for the DIV with just two videos is as follows:-

```
 <div id="videos" style="width: 400px; position: relative; top: 70px; margin-left: 500px; z-index: 2; opacity: 1;">
        <center>
        Preview Video Clips<br><br>
        <iframe width="380" height="223" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/svyqY3EdnBo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><br><br>
        <iframe width="380" height="223" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/K8QlNdFeBZ4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><br><br>
       </center>
    </div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers,

Rob

Comment: Odd - when I use your code above, both videos play independently.

Comment: It turned out I was missing something small that I had already altered on a similar page for a different reason. I had a container DIV element with a z-index parameter that was making some things, in other DIVs within that container and below a certain point on the page, no longer interactive. A very simple fix once it was found.

Answer (score 0):

Your "allowfullscreen" attribute has no value. Try "allowfullscreen = true"
If that doesnt work, try a new DIV for each video?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed putting style="z-index:1;" in iframe